# Movie Weekend Codechef Beginner Section : Runtime Error

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I have written the following code for the problem, ideone doesnt give me runtime error but the compiler for codechef is giving me one. The compiler in codechef is gcc 4.9.2

**Problem** [Link : https://www.codechef.com/problems/MOVIEWKN]

Little Egor is a huge movie fan. He likes watching different kinds of movies: from drama movies to comedy movies, from teen movies to horror movies. He is planning to visit cinema this weekend, but he's not sure which movie he should watch.
There are n movies to watch during this weekend. Each movie can be characterized by two integers Li and Ri, denoting the length and the rating of the corresponding movie. Egor wants to watch exactly one movie with the maximal value of Li × Ri. If there are several such movies, he would pick a one with the maximal Ri among them. If there is still a tie, he would pick the one with the minimal index among them.
Your task is to help Egor to pick a movie to watch during this weekend.

**Expected Input**

The first line of the input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases.

The first line of the test case description contains an integer n(number of films).

The second line of the test case description contains n integers L1, L2, ...,Ln (L is the Length of the movie). The following line contains n integers R1, R2, ..., Rn(R is the Rating of the movie).

**My Input**

 
2 
 
2
 
1 2 
 
2 1 
 
4 
 
2 1 4 1
 
2 4 1 4

**Expected Output**

For each test case, output a single integer i denoting the index of the movie. Note that 1-based indexing is  followed.

**My Output**

 
1
 
2

**Explanation**

In the first example case, both films have the same value of L × R, but the first film has a better rating.
In the second example case, the second and the fourth movies are equally good, but the second movie has a smaller index

**My Solution**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int T;

    cin >> T;
    cin.ignore();

    if (T >= 1 && T <= 5) {

        for (int q = 0; q < T; q++) {


            int n;
            size_t pos;
            cin >> n;
            cin.ignore();

            if (n >= 1 && n <= 100) {

                vector<int> L;
                vector<int> R;
                vector<int> C;

                for (int u = 0; u < n; u++) {

                    int a;
                    cin >> a;
                    cin.ignore();

                    if (a >= 1 && a <= 100) {

                        L.push_back(a);

                    }


                }
                for (int u = 0; u < n; u++) {

                    int a;
                    cin >> a;
                    cin.ignore();

                    if (a >= 1 && a <= 100) {

                        R.push_back(a);

                    }


                }
                for (int u = 0; u < n; u++) {

                    int df = (L[u] * R[u]);
                    C.push_back(df);



                }



                for (size_t u = 0; u < C.size(); u++) {

                    int max = C[0];


                    if (max < C[u]) {

                        max = C[u];
                        pos = u+1;
                    }

                    if (max == C[u]) {

                        if (R[pos-1] < R[u]) { pos = u + 1; }
                        if (R[pos - 1] == R[u]) {

                            if (pos > u) { pos = u + 1; }

                        }

                    }


                }

                cout << pos << endl;


            }

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

After going through some of the questions on runtime error regarding codechef questions, i am guessing the problem is related to accessing an out of boundary element but i am not able to pinpoint the actual problem

Comment: It has nothing to do with the compiler.  Change your vector usage of `[ ]` to `at()`, use the same input, and don't be surprised if both compilers throw an `out_of_range` exception.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have tried your suggestions but the runtime error is still showing up :( . The error is a runtime error with SIGABRT signal

Comment: Can you provide a link to the problem on codeshef?

Comment: Show us the data you're using.  My suggestion is to show you that using the same data (which you never showed us), and changing all the `[ ]` access to `at()`, if you've accessed the vector out-of-bounds, an exception will be thrown by both compilers (I would say **all** compilers).

Comment: @0x499602D2  https://www.codechef.com/problems/MOVIEWKN

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have used the input data mentioned for the problem and i am getting required output as mentioned when i run my code prior to your suggestion on ideone,so i kind of jumped to a conclusion about the problem being a compiler issue. Sorry about that, i am kind of a beginner.

Comment: The question is not self-contained. There is no problem statement.

Comment: @PagadalaVikramaditya Please look at this: http://ideone.com/xmxlB3  It clearly shows that there is a runtime error using your data.  The problem probably is that you're using uninitialized variable `pos` in the array access (look at the usage of `at()`).  So it looks like you didn't do what I stated, and that was to use `at()`.  When using vectors, and you're not using pointers at all, when you get a runtime error, immediately switch to using `at()` instead of `[ ]` -- if you have an out-of-bounds access, you see right away what it is when `at()` is used instead of `[ ]`.

Comment: Also, the reason why both compilers gave different results is that using `[ ]` with an out-of-bounds index is **undefined behavior**.  Since `pos` is uninitialized, it could be 0, 10, 13432432, -124324, 14, you don't know.   Given that, let's use -124324 as the value, thus R[-124324] is out-of-bounds, but doesn't do any harm, thus the program runs without you knowing it's bad.  On the other hand, if you access an out-of-bounds index with `at()`, an `out_of_range` exception is thrown, and in the example at the link, tells you that the number of entries is 2 and your index is out-of-bounds.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for your elaborate explaination. That helped me get a clear idea on how to use (at)operator :)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie   I was new to (at) operator so i had to look up some posts, got an idea that its similar to assert() throwing an exception but wasnt clear about its usage.Your usage helped me get a clear idea on how to implement it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
if (R[pos - 1] < R[u]) { pos = u + 1; }
```

The first time around the loop, `pos` is uninitialised, leading to undefined behaviour.

Simple fix:

add `pos = 1` before the loop

Comment: Too bad the OP didn't do what was stated in the comments about using `at()`.  They would have seen this right away.

Comment: Also note - you are setting `max` back to `C[0]` each time around the loop.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the OP may just have been unlucky and `pos` happened to be an in range value.

Comment: Yes, but if you read the post, ideone was used.  I was able to duplicate the error with no problems.  I also ran this on Visual Studio 2015 -- it has a nice feature letting you know that `pos` is uninitialized, regardless of the value.

Comment: Yes, I agree - I didn't see your ideaone comment to the OP before I posted. VS2015 is what I used to find the error, the debug mode initialises variable to 0xcccccccc which helps to find these problems. I am surprised that neither compiler found the unitiialised variable at compile time though.

Comment: I have referred to the following link  and  made the changes. http://lemire.me/blog/2012/06/20/do-not-waste-time-with-stl-vectors/    Could you please help me as to why pos is retaining its initialized value?        https://ideone.com/OSIWyH            on the contrary even when it is not intialized i still get one as answer https://ideone.com/4oYMQN .   Sorry for all the trouble i am causing you guys.

Comment: @PagadalaVikramaditya -- That's because `pos` is uninitialized.  Like I said, it could have any value, including ones that happen to be ok.  Look again: https://ideone.com/ahoQr3  All I did was added a `cout`, and everything falls apart again.   When a variable is uninitialized, adding unrelated code like a simple `cout` causes the binary image to change, thus the uninitialized value may be different.

Comment: TheDark PaulMcKenzie   I kind of wanted to get my hands dirty on using STL vector instead of using arrays(which would have been way easier), so i apologize for all the trouble i am causing

Comment: For https://ideone.com/OSIWyH the problem is in your reading part - you copy the same value through the whole vector with those `k1` loops. That's why you get an answer of 1 - the program thinks all the movies are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably late but here is my simple solution:

```
t=int(input())
for j in range(0,t):
    n=int(input())
    a=[int(ele) for ele in input().split()]
    b=[int(ele) for ele in input().split()]
    c=[]
    pos=0
    max=-1
    max2=-1
    for i in range(0,n):
        fl=0
        c.append(a[i]*b[i])
        if(max<c[i]):
            max=c[i]
            fl=1
        if(fl==1):
            pos=i+1
            max2=b[i]
        elif(max==c[i]):
            if(max2<b[i]):
                pos=i+1
                max2=b[i]
    print(pos)
```